# WordPress custom post type rewrite rule same as page poyt type

Tags: wordpress

I created custom post type: books
And created rewrite rule for this:

```
$new_rules[ '([^/]+)$' ] = 'index.php?post_type=book&name=$matches[1]';
```

I's works fine! Book URL is:
http://domain.com/bookname/

But when I open pages (default page posty type) I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `with_front` set to false when register your **custom post type**  will remove slug from your custom post type,

> 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'book', 'with_front' => false),

Example : When register your post type using `rewrite` rule. See Manual for [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

```
add_action('init', 'codex_book_init');

function codex_book_init()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Books', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'menu_name' => _x('Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x('Books', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'new_item' => __('New Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'view_item' => __('View Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'all_items' => __('All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'not_found' => __('No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain')
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __('Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'book', 'with_front' => false),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments')
    );

    register_post_type('book', $args);
}
```

Comment: 'with_front' => false added, but URL still:
domain.com/book/bookpost/ not domain.com/bookpost/

Comment: it is because you already registerd this post type copy the source code i have provide and change the custom post type  book to another name for testing purpose you will see the url domain.com/another-name-post/ i have tested the above code with `USE Cases`, i got the same problem with already registered post but got fixed with new test post type using `with_front=>false`.

Answer (score 0):

1. WordPress uses the first matched rule.
2. Your new rule is the same as the rule for pages.
3. Your new rule is being matched earlier than the rule for pages.
4. There's no book found with the name of the page, of course.
5. WordPress stops here (see 1.) and shows you 404 error, which is, actually, 100% correct.

To solve this, enable url base with `'with_front' => true` argument in your `register_post_type` call, so your url will look like `domain.com/book/book_name`